# How to add JSON data to a JTable in JAVA

Tags: java, json, swing, rest, jtable

I am using REST webservice to access the MySQL database. I have created a java swing application for REST client in NetBeans IDE. When I clicked `jButton` I am getting `JSON object` and I set those to a `jTextArea`. Now what I want is to fill the `JTable` from the received `JSON object`. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

> Code that set JSON Object to jTextArea

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/webservice/rest/bdetails/get");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        String json = "";
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
                        json += output;
        }

        conn.disconnect();
        java.lang.reflect.Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<BDetails>>() {
                }.getType();

        List<BDetails> bList = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);

            for( BDetails adr : bList) {
               jTextArea1.append(adr.toString());
               jTextArea1.append("\n");

            }

            System.out.print(json);
        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

> BDetails Class

```
public class BDetails 
{
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    public BDetails() {
    }

    public BDetails(String username, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        this.username = username;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String object = "username: "+username+" firstName: "+firstName+" lastName: "+lastName+" address: "+address;
        return object;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the data of each BDetails object as a unique row to the TableModel.

The basic code would be something like:

```
String[] columnNames = { "Username", "First Name", "Last Name", "Address" };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

for( BDetails detail : bList) 
{
    Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
    row.add(detail.getUserName());
    row.add(detail.getFirstName());
    row.add(detail.getLastName());
    row.add(detail.getAddress();
    model.addRow( row );
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
// add the scrollpane to the frame
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: It Worked. Thank you camickr.